# Using variables in nginx map

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a `maps.conf` with a lot of `map` blocks like

```
map $uri $page_redirect {
  include /etc/nginx/maps/rewrites.map;
}
```

...and a lot of `*.map` files that redirect pages, for instance:

`*/homepage/*` to `*https://example.com*`
and
`*/my-page/*` to `*https://example.com/page/*`

Now I also have some sections of the site where I need to use a variable for a more dynamic redirect.

`/dynamic-page/detail/o5u48i3u5` should redirect to `https://example.com/show/page/detail/o5u48i3u5`

What I have tried to far was this:

```
~^/dynamic-page/detail/(?<location>.*)/$          https://example.com/show/page/detail/$location/;
```

The redirect itself works, but it won't replace $location in the URL so it looks like this: `https://example.com/show/page/detail/$location/`

I have even tried

```
~^/dynamic-page/detail/(.*)/$          https://example.com/show/page/detail/$1/;
```

but the URL is `https://example.com/show/page/detail/$1/`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is your nginx version?